# New LDAP User with Powershell

Tags: powershell, ldap

I have the challenge to create new LDAP Users with a Powershell Script.
I have googled a lot but I found no good results...

This is my Code to get Users from the LDAP...

```
    $authenticationType  = [System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes]::ServerBind
$objSearcherRoot = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://***.local.com:777/ou=user,o=company", "uid=testuser,ou=system,o=company", "password" , $authenticationType)
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher 
$objSearcher.SizeLimit= 0
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objSearcherRoot
$objSearcher.Filter = "cn=$cn"
$result = $objSearcher.FindAll()
```

My Problem is, I don't know how to insert a new LDAP User (not Active Directory)
It would be really nice if someone could help me... ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAP does not support "inserts", but supports "adds". The LDAP client must create an entry and transmit that entry to the directory server using the ADD request. The server returns an ADD result to the LDAP client which contains information about the success or failure of the ADD request. So, check the documentation for information on transmitting an ADD request to the directory server and interpreting the subsequent response.

The LDAP client must have permission to ADD an entry (a user in this case). This involves using the BIND request to change the authorization state of the connection to one which permits adding an entry at the designated place in the directory information tree.

Perhaps this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876635/adding-users-to-ad-with-powershell) will help.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for this interesting and good description.
Do you know if this is possible with Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, I've done it. You need to bind to the LDAP server using a System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection object (let's say $c) and then create a System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.AddRequest object and populate its attributes (I'm only showing a couple in this example):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices.Protocols")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Net")
$c = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection -ArgumentList "***.local.com:777,uid=testuser,ou=system,o=company", "password" , $authenticationType"
$c.Bind()
$r = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.AddRequest
$r.DistinguishedName = "uid= xxxx, ou=user, o=company"
$r.Attributes.Add((New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute -ArgumentList "objectclass",@("top","organizationalPerson","person","inetorgperson","inetuser","mailrecipient","pwmuser","posixAccount"))) | Out-Null
$r.Attributes.Add((New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryAttribute -ArgumentList "cn",($FirstName+" "+$LastName))) | Out-Null
```

Then just send the request:

```
$c.SendRequest($r)
```

Answer (score -1):

You say "create new LDAP Users" but you could create AD users and then they would be available Using LDAP.

I used a [script from Microsoft](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Create-Active-7e6a3978) to do something similar.

If you look through the code, you should be able to see how they did it. We used their code with a few tweaks to do what we needed.

-jim

Comment: Jim:  You missed the point that this was running against an LDAP instance that was NOT Active Directory.